# Can WebAPI endpoint, but disregard reply

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I need to log certain front end events, and would liek to know if there is a way to call a .Net WebAPI endpoint (POST) with a small amount of data, and disregard the reply.

I have two options maybe. From my UI, call the javascript fetch API, and not have a `.then((result => {` ... or, maybe better, is to call endpoint from my fetch method, and check that it was a 200. But on the .Net side, basically return a 200 instantly, if the endpoint was discovered correctly, but on the .Net side, create a thread or something that has no reply? i.e. The API gets the request, sends the message off to my logging function (which does the database persistence), but disregard the result. Just return the 200, and THEN start the back end logging.

Note my api calling code is all within a fetchData wrapper, which returns a new Promise. If, when I call my wrapper, eg `DataAccessor.Log(myLogData)` - If I don't have a `.then` after that, does the code continue past that line, and disregard the result of the promise?

Getting a 200 would be nice, but I'm really looking for efficiency that has zero effect on the user experience.

Comment: The request will be made regardless of having a `then()` for response. Might want a `catch()` in case you need to repeat it for some reason. Even if there was a `then()` it really shouldn't affect UX  anyway

Comment: Thanks. So the request will go, and the end point will do it's thing, and even though the api call might take 300ms .... because there's no '.then`, the ui code will continue and disregard any response? Basically, fire-and-forget? I guess the catch might be handy. And as long as I'm not using anything from the result, you're right. UI code shouldn't be effected. Interesting.

Comment: Yes...even if there was a `then()` and request took 2 minutes it wouldn't affect UX because it is asynchronous and non blocking